# Im trying to update my Google map location on the scripts.js page but something must be conflicting

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

The contact page I'm trying to update is http://gorillapallets.com/contact/

I've added the new location iFrame code to the scripts.js file, included in the code below.

the code I'm dealing with is:

```
if (wWidth > 500) {
    $('map').append('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/1210+Kona+Dr,+Compton,+CA+90220/@33.8700807,-118.2444743,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m3!11m2!2skZjwuM0gE8c2O9o4XAFIeB2LY3Oa4Q!3e1!3m4!1s0x80c2cb2e464e8319:0x20ffac28fc066871!8m2!3d33.8700807!4d-118.2422803" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>')

} else {
    $('#conditional-map').append('<img alt="big image" src="http://10.0.1.140/gorilla/wp-content/themes/gorilla2014/images/gorilla-pallets-map.jpg" />')
}
```

They had just gotten rid of the small map so we don't need the if and else. I tried commenting out js code line by line to find a conflict, but the js code above just won't update on the live contact page. The map location showing on the live page is what I'm trying to update... I've checked in WordPress to see if anything there is conflicting. It is possible wp is conflicting somehow but I couldn't find anything.